# Create a JSON object from simple string in C#

Tags: c#, json

I am getting a string as a response from my command line. I want to convert it into  a json string , which i will later use to convert to a c# object.

```
The string Response(sub variable has this string as value) 
Access Token      00D0E00000019dU!
Alias             accp
Client Id         SalesforceDevelopmentExperience
Connected Status  Connected
Id                00D
Instance Url      https://my.salesforce.com
Username          ankur
```

tried converting it into json by below code

```
string[] subArray = sub.Split('\n'); 
            string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(subArray);                       
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(output);
```

Token Class

```
public class Token
    {
        public string AccessToken { get; set; }
        public string Alias { get; set; }

    }
```

It Gives this error

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Token' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path '', line 1, position 1
```

.

Converted JSON

```
["Access Token      00D0E00000019dU!AQU","Alias             accp","Client Id         SalesforceDevelopmentExperience","Connected Status  Connected","Id                00D","Instance Url      https://my.salesforce.com","Username          ankur"]
```

Any Help to convert the string into a JSON/C# object?

Comment: is `sub` the above string? you'll have to parse it further?

Comment: yes sub is the string which has the value.Edited the question

Comment: other than `.Split`ing on new lines - have you tried parsing it differently?

Comment: No i have not tried any thing else, I am open for suggestion . Can you put a example of other approach and paste it as a answer

Comment: What is the gap between the property name and value? It looks like spaces so you're going to have to split that string by length.

Comment: What does the json look like? Can you post what it's trying to deserialize?

Comment: It's basically telling you that the string is not in the accepted json format. Have a look at the spec for how to properly format key-value pairs in json: http://json-schema.org/specification.html

Comment: @DavidG if i split by sapce it will be hard to get the values

Comment: @ankur That's why I said split by length (as per my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks far simpler to forget about JSON and parse manually. For example:

```
//split up the source string into name value pairs
var nameValues = sub.Split('\n')
    .Select(s => new
    {
        Name = s.Substring(0, 18).Trim(), 
        Value = s.Substring(18).Trim() 
    });

//Create the token object manually
var token = new Token
{
    AccessToken = nameValues.Single(v => v.Name == "Access Token").Value,
    Alias = nameValues.Single(v => v.Name == "Alias").Value
};
```

Comment: it worked like a charm. Many thanks for your help. Can you explain this s.Substring(0, 18) how did you came up with the number 18 here

Comment: `Substring` just takes a portion of a string. In this case we take the first 18 characters which is the left part of each line, then all the characters are the first 18 for the value.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should parse this 'sub' string in different way.
Second you should create JObject not trying serialize Array of strings.

Try this

```
// Splitting into string lines
var subArray = sub.Split('\n')
    .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));

JObject tokenJObj = new JObject();
foreach (var oneSub in subArray)
{
// I assume that the value will be after the last empty character
    tokenJObj.Add(
        oneSub.Substring(0, oneSub.LastIndexOf(' ')).Trim(), 
        oneSub.Substring(oneSub.LastIndexOf(' ') + 1));
}
string tokenStringJson1 = tokenJObj.ToString();
// or
string tokenStringJson2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tokenJObj);
```

Then just add correct attribute on propteries inside your model

```
public class Token
    {
        [JsonProperty("Access Token")]
        public string AccessToken { get; set; }

        // In this property attribute is not requied
        [JsonProperty("Alias")]
        public string Alias { get; set; }
    }
```